# Change Bluetooth name Python

Tags: python, bluetooth, ubuntu-10.10

I'm using PyBluez on Ubuntu 10.10. I would like to know how is possible to change the bluetooth name of the local device in software. I couldn't find any command related..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke `org.bluez.Adapter.SetProperty(u'Name', u'New name here')` in the `/org/bluez/<pid>/<device>` object path on the `org.bluez` D-Bus bus.

Comment: Is this related to PyBluez package at all?

Comment: @Senthil: No. Most likely that property is not exposed there, and requires low-level D-Bus access.

Comment: How can I implement this? How can I access D-Bus (it's the first time I hear of it..)